# send GET (ajax-like) request with Flash

Tags: ajax, flash

I don't know Flash at all =)

I have the following code

```
> on (release) {

> getURL("register.html#","blank");

}
```

It want the program to send additional (silent, ajax) request to `test/adder.php` to activate a counter when user presses a button. If `adder.php` is executed, the counter increments. `adder.php` outputs nothing, it has to be just executed.

Jquery code that was doing this was

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test/adder.php',
});
```

If it is possible, could you change the button code 'cause I don't have any software here.

http://kuperfild.ru/flash-button.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good text to read is [this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=525634). I make some code changes so it should work now, you can try it [here](http://fuckingsolarprominence.com/share/test.rar).